# Inaniloquent or Inaniloquently?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

It was an **inaniloquent** chat room.

But is it common to use the word **inaniloquently** in another context? for instance:

He speaks **inaniloquently**.

Comment: It is ***never*** common to use *inaniloquent* at all.

Comment: Google has 16,600 hits for "inaniloquent." Neither form appears in [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inaniloquent%2Cinaniloquently&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=). Like Jim said, neither is common by any reasonable definition.

Comment: I'd never heard of this one, so I checked [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93089?redirectedFrom=inaniloquent+#eid). It is actually there, but they list it (along with derivatives **inaniloquence, inaniloquous, inaniloquution**) as ***Obsolete (rare)***. I don't think I'll be planning to remember and use it myself.

Comment: @Jim @ Kevin yes it's not common to use this word.
@ FumbleFingers I saw the definition in this [webpage](http://digitalmediauconn.org/rachele/projects/01_definition/index.htm), 
yet l wasn't sure how to use the word with the possible derivatives.
Thank you all for the comments!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can’t see the OED entry but I assumed it was a (possibly newer?) portmanteau of *inane* and *eloquence*

Comment: @Jim: OED says it's from *Latin **inānis** inane adj. + **loquent-em,** present participle of **loqui** to speak.* But their last cite for ***inaniloquent*** is 1656 (last cite for any derivatives is 1727). My guess is the current "resurgence" (such as it is) is fueled more by pretentiousness than its usefulness as *le mot juste*.